# TestNG parallel execution on AMD A8 machines not working

Tags: selenium-webdriver, parallel-processing, testng

I am trying to run following test in parallel using testNG. The test run in parallel in Intel processors but on AMD processors they are running in sequential order.

testng.xml :

```
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests">
     <test name="Test1">    
        <parameter name="RowNoStart" value="0"></parameter>
        <parameter name="RowNoEnd" value="10"></parameter>  
            <classes>
                <class name="com.tests.TestClass1"></class>
            </classes>      
    </test> 
     <test name="Test2">    
        <parameter name="RowNoStart" value="11"></parameter>
        <parameter name="RowNoEnd" value="12"></parameter>  
            <classes>
                <class name="com.tests.TestClass2"></class>
            </classes>      
    </test>
</suite>
```

Please let me know how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you please confirm on the following ? Are you using the same TestNG version across both the machines ? How are you ascertaining that the version is the same ? If TestNG 6.13.1 was involved in one of these machines, then it could be due to [this](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1636) bug which will be fixed and available in `6.14`. You can either try to use TestNG `6.14-SNAPSHOT` and see if that helps or try [this](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1636#issuecomment-349182219) workaround and see if that helps.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan Thanks for pointing out this bug :) 
Yes, I have installed testNG from Eclipse marketplace on one of my machine few days ago. It may have installed the latest version 6.13.1. 
I think reverting it to older version can do my job.

Comment: Have you tried applying the workaround that I suggested, before reverting back ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that but it wasn't working. Test ran in sequential order. I downgraded testNg to 6.11 and it is working now. :)

Answer (score 0):

From the `testng.xml` you have shared it is pretty clear that though you have mentioned **parallel="tests"** you haven't mentioned about the `parameter` **`thread-count`**. You need to add the `parameter` **`thread-count`** as follows :

```html
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
     <test name="Test1">    
     <parameter name="RowNoStart" value="0"/>
     <parameter name="RowNoEnd" value="10"/> 
            <classes>
                <class name="com.tests.TestClass1"/>
            </classes>      
     </test> 
     <test name="Test2">    
     <parameter name="RowNoStart" value="11"/>
     <parameter name="RowNoEnd" value="12"/>
            <classes>
                <class name="com.tests.TestClass2"/>
            </classes>      
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried running the code with the parameter thread-count="2". But again I got the same result. The machine with AMD Processor run it in sequential order. Intel processor run it Parallel. Don't know, what's going on?

Comment: If `thread-count` is not specified it defaults to `5` and `10` for data providers. See [here](http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd.php)

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan Thanks, So ideally when we mention `parallel="tests"`, should `thread-count` be mentioned or not?

Comment: It is required only when you don't want to be using the default values. In all other cases, thread-count and dataprovider-thread-count can be conveniently ignored.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan Can you please direct me to any documentation on this topic?

Comment: The DTD link I shared by itself is one form of a document. The other is obviously the source code.